# Gridview row edit issues with invisible columns

Tags: asp.net, sql, gridview

I am creating a website for school project using Visual Studio 2010 in VB, my knowledge with this is not the greatest. I have an issue in editing a row of a gridview. I have a table that stores user prescription information like:

- ID
- username
- medication
- dosage
- times a day
- times weekly(optional)

To neaten up the grid-view i made a couple of columns invisible by setting the column's visible property to false (a user does not need to see row ID or their username on every row).

However, when I attempt to edit a row, and I click "Update" I get an error that the

> invisible username column cannot contain a null value due to the table definitions.

I was assuming since the data is already stored that there would not be any null values, and that it just would not be visible. However, this does not seem to be the case.

If I make the column for username visible, everything works fine.

So my question is, **is it possible to edit a row that has an invisible column? Or will I have to make that column visible and make the textbox read-only** for users to be able to edit a row successfully?

I resolved the issue. The code that it generated for the update command was:

`UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Prescriptions] SET [UserName] = @UserName, [Prescriptions] = @Prescriptions, [Dosage] = @Dosage, [TimesDaily] = @TimesDaily, [TimesWeekly] = @TimesWeekly WHERE [ID] = @ID">`

By removing `[UserName] = @UserName` I can now edit a row with the invisible username column.

Comment: paste some Code What You Tried...???

Comment: i am with ganesh please show us your code???

Answer (score 0):

@d_wiegand: You could use [firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) to debug the page. Check the hidden fields whether it is contains any value with the tool. I am pretty sure that you are not getting values in the hidden boxes. that is the problem